# Can you remove nvidia_modeset without removing the rest of the driver?

Tags: nvidia, kernel-modules, gpu, gpu-passthrough, nomodeset

I'm trying to prevent nvidia driver from modesetting as an integrated GPU (i915) is doing it. I'm only using this nvidia card on linux for rendering (PRIME), no modesetting.  I've tried blacklisting it in modprobe.d and via kernel options, but it still gets loaded.

Nvidia driver doesn't seem to have any configuration option to tell it to stop trying to modeset the displays when they get connected. Is there any other way to force a module to not be loaded?

I've tried to just remove the `/usr/lib/modules/6.5.9-arch2-1/extramodules/nvidia-modeset.ko.xz` module file, but then `dracut-rebuild` won't work (refuses to produce initrd).

Comment: Tried `options nvidia-drm modeset=0`?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've tried that. Still nvidia_modeset gets loaded. I've eventually gave up on this and solved my problem in another way (that doesn't involve removing nvidia_modeset).